# Mysql fulltext search doesn't find, if searched string is not separated with spaces

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm building a small search with PHP. Here's an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM tools
WHERE name LIKE "%example%"
ORDER BY name;
```

A couple of names:

```
this example will be found
this example1 will not be found
```

It only finds the rows, if the string that is being searched is a separate word. Any advice? :)

Thanks,
Martti Laine

Comment: can you post your table definitions?

Comment: maybe you can use a wildcard at the end of the term?

Comment: I don't believe you, the SQL you are showing us is using wildcard search, where the hack is the full-text search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the following script

```
CREATE TABLE tools ( 
  name TEXT, 
  FULLTEXT (name) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT tools VALUES('this example will be found');
INSERT tools VALUES('this example1 will not be found');

SELECT * FROM tools
WHERE name LIKE "%example%"
ORDER BY name;
```

Which gave the output

```
this example will be found 
this example1 will not be found
```

I even got the same output when running the `SELECT` without the FULLTEXT index.

Can you post the DDL for the creation of your database and any errors you receive?
Also, does the SQL execute correctly in MySQL Workbench or have you only tried it from your PHP code?

(I realise this is not strictly an answer to your question but posting as an answer allows for better formatting of the text)

**EDIT:** After seeing the comment from ajreal I also tried

```
SELECT * FROM tools
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('example')
```

and this time it did not return any rows...

Comment: There was an error with the cron job that handles filling the table, so there were empty fields that were causing sql errors. I finally got it working. I'm sorry for this totally unnecessary question. Thanks for everyone who tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

That's the way it's supposed to work.  MySQL's [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) using what's known as *stemming*  to build the search index.  So it'll take a word like *shopping* and store *shop* (since it's the same word).  That way, when you search for one variant of the word, it can find all variants of the word.

However, in your case, that may not be the greatest situation.  Well, for that, you have 2 possibilities:

1. Use `LIKE` with Full Text searching.

   Well, LIKE performs a direct case-insensitive search.  Full Text Search performs a stemmed word search.  Both have significant flaws.  But together they will let you hit a broader scope of results.
2. Use a 3pd search engine tool such as [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

   This will likely be the most efficient option, since these tools are both very good in how they search, and are *very* fast.  Basically, the tools indexes the MySQL database from time to time (depending on the setup), and then you search against the tool instead of MySQL.  This is the most robust option, and the most flexible.